# Error when adding foreign key to newly created table (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am trying to alter table product to add a constraint of type foreign key for field petCat_ID so that it references table petCategory(ID). I just created table petCat_ID and i am getting a "Cannot add or update a child row" error.

This is the commands I performed to get this error:

```
 Alter table product
-> ADD CONSTRAINT FK_petCatID
-> FOREIGN KEY (petCat_ID)
-> REFERENCES productCategory(ID);
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Note: petCat_ID is in table product and productCategory is a different table.

Comment: This is the error I got: ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`petstore`.`#sql-87a_42`, CONSTRAINT `FK_petCatID` FOREIGN KEY (`petCat_ID`) REFERENCES `productcategory` (`id`))

Comment: Considering we don't know the rest of your database, this is difficult to answer, as your syntax appears to be correct (I think). I would recommend dropping the table, and adding it again with it's constraints  and relationships defined in the creation script.

Comment: @TerryDorsey do you know what that error code means?

Comment: product and productCategory are separate tables would that have something to do with it?

Comment: The error just means that it didn't work because some other rule conflicts with what you want to do. If you are trying to modify a database that already has enumerated tables, I strongly advise instead that you build the new database table structure and then do a migration from your current database to the new one.

As I've said before, I can't really help any more than just telling you what I'd do. I need an ER diagram to know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

In my comments I've mentioned that I need a clearer idea of what kind of database structure you have, but I have a series of things that will help you work through the problem you're having.

1. If an ALTER statement isn't working, and you have good syntax, it is because what you are doing conflicts with an already present rule.
2. Sometimes, doing a DROP TABLE command, followed by creating the table again can fix problems. This can be problematic if there are dependencies that keep you from dropping the table.
3. When things get dire, try looking at the script you used to make the DB in the first place. Modify it and see if you can get the properties you want. Once you do, make a new database table structure and migrate your table entries over to the new database from the old one.
4. [I made a github repository here](https://github.com/geektechniquestudios/AmtrackDatabase/blob/master/DatabaseScipts.txt) wherein I made a third normal form version of what the customer facing Amtrack database would look like, and even wrote scripts to add data to the tables, with examples. There are images showing the ER structure. I included my creation script, broken into each table's creation in specific order. It should be a good reference for how to assign table relationships, and that will give you a good idea of what you can alter. **Disclaimer** I wrote it for SSMS, but I don't believe I used anything SSMS specific I THINK that code should work in MySQL.